Inkscape Synfig: how do I import multiple Inkscape send into Synfig and link the objects?
I import 2 drawings from Inkscape into Synfig, one before and one after. How do I tell Synfig that an object/layer on before is the same as an object/layer on after?
The goal is to animate between 2 drawings.
